# Accessing mySQL DB through a Java/jersey REST Resource

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jdbc, jersey

Do I put the data source lookup in the constructor of a resource, or should it occur everytime I want to use the database? Or in a different class all together? These are the two lines i'm talking about and don't know where I should move them:

```
initContext = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/dbName");
```

What other methods can I use to seperate the DB work from the GET method? Here is my code so you cna see it all in one method, which is what i want to change:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
            public List<Item> getItemsBrowser(){

                DataSource dataSource = null;
                java.sql.Connection connection;
                java.sql.Statement statement;

                List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();


                javax.naming.Context initContext;
                try {
                    initContext = new InitialContext();
                    dataSource = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/dbName");
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ResultSet resultSet = null;

                try {
                    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                    statement = connection.createStatement();

                    String query = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS";

                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

                    // Fetch each row from the result set
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                      String a = resultSet.getString("itemID");

                      String b = resultSet.getString("itemDescription");

                      //Assuming you have a user object
                      Item item = new Item(a, b);

                      items.add(item);
                    }


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return items;
            }
```

Any advice is appreicated, thanks.

Comment: Download NetBeans and use the wizard called: Create RESTFul web services from database: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Comment: Is there anything similar for eclipse? Is it not simple to do by hand?

Comment: Sure, you can do it by hand and using eclipse, it's trivial. But I don't have the time to setup an example for you. You may use that NB's wizard just for learning purposes.

Comment: I only really want to know where those two lines should be. In the constructor for every resource? Or is a datasoruce supposed to be used accross other resources too. For example an items resource an customers resource will use the same data source. But will be in different resource classes and at different uri's

Comment: In the Java EE 6 way, you can avoid to use explicitly the InitialContext, DataSource, Connection and Statement objects. That's why I suggested you to have a look to some tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have some `ItemDAO` (data access object), which will retirieve the required `Item` from datasource using some `Connection Pool`. And then these two lines will be in `DAO` initialization.